# Wordpress - Customize Watson Assistant plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, artificial-intelligence, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I'd like to customize my chat box (Watson Assistant Chat Bot) and include my own CSS. I know I can set some changes on the plugin panel but I'd like to do more. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to leverage WordPress itself to customize the look and feel via CSS.

You can do so from the sidebar menu **Appearance -> Edit CSS**.

Alternatively, your theme might offer you an option to write custom CSS code (and there also free custom CSS plugins you could install). But unless you have a good reason not to, the suggestion above should work well for you.